# How to use $_FILES["file"]["size"]?

Tags: php

how can I see if the file loaded weighs less than 5MB? I am using

```
$ _FILES ["file"] ["size"]
```

but I do not know how to set 5mb, because the value must be expressed in bytes, from what I understand. So how to do

```
$ _FILES ["file"] ["size"] <(5mb)
```

thanks

Comment: So... convert 5 megabytes to bytes? Google straight-up *gives* you [your answer](https://www.google.com/search?q=5+megabytes+to+bytes).

Comment: I asked because I was not sure that was expressed in bytes...

Comment: 2 seconds in the manual would of answered that. http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php "The size, in bytes, of the uploaded file."

Answer (score 51, accepted):

5MB -> 5 * 1024 * 1024 bytes

or... if you're a storage vendor, then it's actually 5 * 1000 * 1000.

Comment: Storage vendors sometimes use 1000 over 1024 because they sell by the MB or GB and so they can sell you less bytes per unit of storage. Here is an article on the subject http://boulderapps.co/post/gb-vs-gib-1024-vs-1000

Answer (score 143):

To keep code clear, I often define units as constants:

```
define('KB', 1024);
define('MB', 1048576);
define('GB', 1073741824);
define('TB', 1099511627776);
```

Then you can simply do your condition like

```
if ($_FILES['file']['size'] < 5*MB)
```