# How to get PDF or DOC file size?

Tags: php

Trying to get a pdf document file size, but it is giving me `Warning: filesize(): stat failed for`...

What I have tried:

```
    //get original temporary name
    $temp_name = $_FILES['userDegreeFile']['tmp_name'];

    //original file path with original name
    $inital_name = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "super/IMG/user_files/user_files_".$userFirstName."_".$user_id."/" . $temp_name; 

    //get the file size
    $file_size = filesize($inital_name);
```

When running this I get the error stated above. The file name in the error is `D:/Programs/wamp/www/super/IMG/user_files/user_files_Jim_52/D:\Programs\wamp\tmp\php70B9.tmp`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you think that path looks strange?

Comment: @u_mulder you sir are correct.

Comment: $_FILES['userDegreeFile']['size']  for get file size.

Answer (score 2):

Always use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, its compatible for both linux and windows path.

```
$inital_name = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "super".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."IMG".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."user_files".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."user_files_".$userFirstName."_".$user_id.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."$temp_name;
```

Another way is `$_FILES ["file"]["size"];` Check here for more info : [How to use $_FILES["file"]["size"]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758191/how-to-use-filesfilesize)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this I think this will help you

`

// outputs e.g.  somefile.txt: 1024 bytes

$filename = 'somefile.txt';
echo $filename . ': ' . filesize($filenam`) . ' bytes';

?>
`