# getimagesize returns warning if file size is more than 2 MB

Tags: php

I am trying to get images from users. Now if file size is more than 2 MB, my script should return a message to the user saying that there is a file size restriction of 2 MB. For this I have kept a check as follows -

```
if($_FILES["QuestionImage"]["size"] > 2097152){
     echo "File size is more than 2 MB";
}else{
     $check = getimagesize($_FILES["QuestionImage"]["tmp_name"]);
     ...... 
}
```

However, if the file size is more than 2 MB, the script still gets into the else section. I do not know why this is happening. I have tested with a restriction of 1 MB and tried to upload files of 1.4 MB. In that case the code works perfectly. However, in that same code if the file size is 2 MB, it still gets into the else section and getimagesize returns error. Any pointer?

Comment: How much bigger than 2MB are you testing? are you testing something like 5MB. I don't think 2087152 bytes is exactly 2MB.

Comment: Print out the value of `$_FILES["QuestionImage"]["size"]` and make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: That was a typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: I have also tried to print out the value. Whenever the file size is more than 2 MB. It actually returns a size of 0

Comment: Somebody posted a solution in between, which I cannot find any more. That solution actually works. But I need to know the fundamental problem. I am posting the solution anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This solution was posted by somebody else, which was then deleted. It works. But I need to understand the fundamental problem

```
if(filesize($_FILES['QuestionImage']['tmp_name']) > 2097152){
    echo "File size is more than 2 MB";
 }else{
   $check = getimagesize($_FILES["QuestionImage"]["tmp_name"]);
    ...... 
  }
```

Comment: Lets do the multiplication here, 2 MB = (2 * 1024 * 1024) bytes = 2097152 bytes, not 2087152 bytes.

Comment: That was a type mate. What I am trying to say is that when the file size is accessed in the above way it works. But the original thing did not. Why

Comment: @MarkB's answer will give you a perspective of what's *might be* going on here, [http://stackoverflow.com/a/14758212/5517143](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14758212/5517143)