# File size error code not working

Tags: php, php-5.6, php-5.5

I have written below lines of code

```
<?php

$uniqId = uniqid('file_');
$root = $_REQUEST['root'];

$target_file = "uploads/".basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] )
{
    echo 'Error';
}
else if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2097152) 
{
  echo "SizeError";
}
else if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "docx" && $imageFileType != "pdf") 
{
  echo "ExtensionError";
}
else 
{   
   if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $root.$uniqId.".".$imageFileType))
   {
       echo $uniqId.".".$imageFileType;
   }
}
```

?>

If I upload 5 mb file, the code is jumped to simple "Error" condition. I want  that it should display SizeError. Please help!!!

Comment: else if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 5242880)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758191/how-to-use-filesfilesize?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: According to my opinion `if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] )
{
    echo 'Error';
}` is not needed at all

Comment: the question is not about size, the main issue is error message being displayed.

Comment: set 5000000 bytes in condition if you are strongly checking condition @nida

Comment: May I suggest you take a look at my answer to this question: [Full Secure Image Upload Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509334/full-secure-image-upload-script/38712921#38712921). As it is right now, your script is extremely insecure. So much, that someone is able to harm your server and your visitors. My answer explains in detail on how to tackle all of this. And at the end, you will find a download link to library which is very easy to use. This also includes limiting file sizes and handling multiple files at the same time.

Comment: Error message is not printing because your condition is wrong

Comment: yes in this line  if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2097152) { echo "SizeError. }

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size - I think you file isn't even uploaded

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative way to get size

```
if (filesize($target_file) > 2097152) 
{
  echo "SizeError";
}
```

But firstly I think there is an error `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` at `$_FILES['file']['error']`. UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE=1  You can increase it in php.ini. Add or modify this in your php.ini for example yo increase max_file_size = 25mb:

```
upload_max_filesize = 25M
```

After modifying php.ini your code should work too:

```
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] )
{
    echo 'Error';
}
else if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2097152) 
{
  echo "SizeError";
}
```

To check your php.ini settings call:

```
echo phpinfo();
```

You will see your settings, find `upload_max_filesize` it's 2mb as default value. Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Not my downvote, but if your answer includes _"Try this"_, it's very likely not an answer to the question. You didn't test it. You didn't verify if it'll solve the issue. You're taking a gamble.

Comment: @NidaAmin I have improved my answer, I think i found solution

Answer (score 0):

check this condition first `if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2097152)` then check others.

You probably get the `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` at `$_FILES['file']['error']` which is qual to 1. You can increase it in php.ini. Change this in your php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 25M
```

Comment: it is not working again... if i give this as first condition.. the file 5 mb get uploaded

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting "error" is because of this line:

```
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] )
```

If you read the documentation here: [PHP: Upload Error Messages Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), then you'll notice that there are several values that can be returned with `$_FILES['file']['error']`. It returns 0 when there are no errors. But it returns 1 if

> The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in
>   php.ini.

And it returns 2 if:

> The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was
>   specified in the HTML form.

In both cases 0 is smaller than 1 or 2. So your script is returning you "Error". Because the condition evaluates to true.

You need to either change the condition, or check for the file size first.

Comment: you are right but i want that this if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2097152) should work

Comment: now i will eliminate first condiion but the condition if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2097152) does not work

Comment: @NidaAmin Just change `if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ){ .. } else if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2097152)` to `if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2097152){ ... } else if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ){ .. }` and you're good to go. As I said, just check for the file size first, then for errors.

Comment: @NidaAmin Also, make sure you get _meaningfull_ errors returned. It's cool to echo "error", but that's not telling you anything. It doesn't tell you _what_ the error is. Instead, try something like `echo "Error: ". $_FILES['file']['error'];`. Now you'll see which error code is being returned. That can tell you what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2097152) if i use this condition first, it still does not throw SizeError message upon upload of large file than 2097152

Comment: @NidaAmin Like I said, make sure you get _Meaningfull errors_. I can't help you if you tell me "it doesn't work". I'm not some wizard that magicly knows _what_ exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue,and got the solution.
Codeigniter allows you to upload the image of size less than 2mb.but if you want to upload the image of 5 mb than you should add this line in your .htaccess file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
```

After adding this line in your .htaccess file,your code will work fine.